# BOOST_TYPEOF returns int instead of const int

Tags: c++, boost, constants, typeof

Can you please explain why this prints `1`? Should not `BOOST_TYPEOF` return `const int`. How one can check if function returns `const` without using c++11 features?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

const int f_const_int() {return 1;}

int main()
{
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(f_const_int()) type;
    std::cout << (boost::is_same<type, int>::value) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a prvalue expression has type *cv* `int`, that cv-qualifier is ignored. [expr]/6:

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`,” where `T` is a
>   cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
>   is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

The macro does thus never receive the information that the return type was `const`.
Possible workaround:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp>

// […]
typedef boost::function_traits<BOOST_TYPEOF(f_const_int)>::result_type type;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8e67f506759733c).

Comment: What's the reasoning behind dropping the *cv* qualifications here?

Comment: @Barry Perhaps because cv-qualifiers of prvalues are insignificant. But if we don't have to deal with them, defining stuff in [expr] is eased.

Comment: The data being passed to `BOOST_TYPEOF` is an rvalue. It is unnamed, so, const or not, you have no way to modify it without assigning it to an lvalue, which would have to be declared as const for the assignment to not complain.

Comment: @Columbo Can we use the same workaround with member functions? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html here is written that it is not possible. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @Ashot You cannot use function_traits with member functions. And really, providing fairly complete traits for member functions can get very tedious in C++03 as you need douzens of partial specializations. I strongly recommend you to start using C++11 if possible, as everything becomes a lot easier there.